# Function(method) is executing twice although only being called once

Tags: reactjs

In my React App, within once of my components, I've defined a method and then called it once within render(). However, it seems to be executing twice and I have no idea what could be causing it, because nothing I can think of would cause a re-render of the app or anything like that.

This is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


export class MainSetDisplay extends Component {

    createGroups() {
        console.log("Hello World") // <-- Should log once, but logging twice
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                {this.createGroups()}

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MainSetDisplay
```

Obviously this should only console.log Hello World once, although I'm getting it twice. (I've checked it's not coming from anywhere else.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @mjwills I've edited it down as much as I can think of, hopefully that meets what you mean with MRE? Quite tricky with react components short of condensing all into the index.js file

Comment: type debugger instead of console and follow its execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a sandbox project based on your code and it showed just once time.

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-lamarr-5ejmv

maybe the problem is in the parent component(s) which renders this component.

Comment: Nice little resource there. Found the issue thanks, it was caused higher up as suggested through sloppy coding which was causing a state update twice, thus re-rendering.

Ah the joys of debugging :-/